# Write better repetitive excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to figure out if there is a better method to write this formula without having to repeat the MID command so many times.

=IFERROR(IF(FIND("/",MID(C2,25,100))>0,LEFT(MID(C2,25,100),FIND("/",MID(C2,25,100))-1)),MID(C2,25,100))

Example data:

corp.mycompany.com/Here/Location

corp.mycompany.com/Here/Location/OtherOU

The results of both of these will be "Location"

Is there a better way to write the formula?

Comment: if you are using Excel 365, try **LET** function. If you never used it before, you can google it. Exceljet.net has some good examples.

Comment: Using Excel 2016, which doesn't appear to have the LET command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the string after the second forward slash up until the third forward slash, you can use `FILTERXML` and then `INDEX` the result if you have the newest version of Excel. For example:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),3)
```

If you want the string after the third forward slash up until the fourth, just replace 3 with 4 in the formula, etc.

Comment: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[3]")` would do the same, avoiding INDEX.

Comment: Turning it in to and XML string so that it is easier to handle is a good method.  Both solutions so far are something that I did not think of.  Will be able to use these in other spots.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

B1

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),198,99))
```

[image]

Comment: Very creative use of the SUBSTITUTE and REPT functions.  Took me a little work and testing to figure out how this actually worked.  Thank you.